# Error query with single quote

Tags: json, quotes, encode

I have problem with single quotes in my query:

```
myquery =" select x from sometable where x = 'abc' ";
String enc = URLEncoder.encode(myquery, "utf-8");
```

The result in *enc*:  x%3D%27abc%27

Then I use HTTP Connection to parse *myquery* with php file//.  I get the error:

> Errorquery: select x from sometable where x =\'abc\'

Is there problem with *myquery* (single quotes/'abc')?

Comment: don't think it's a good idea to send sql queries in url

Comment: Single quote should work in the query. Could you be a bit more specific in the code part?

Comment: ya, but i want to solve myproblem first, why i got error when i use statement with single quote

Comment: http://....file.php?var=enc //file php has json_encode() function i get errorquery : ..........\'abc\'

Comment: could you please check if the query executes on mysql and make sure that the column's data type accepts a string to compare with?

Comment: when i execute my query on mysql or on my file php, its work.--but when i parse via http using urlencoder.encode, its error..

Comment: my file.php :  <?php
$myq = $_GET['var'];
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('ta', $link) or die('Cannot select the DB');
/* grab the posts from the db */
$query = "$myq";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die('Errorquery:  '.$query); 
$rows = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
$data = "{value:".json_encode($rows)."}";
echo $data; 
?>

Comment: http://10.0.2.2/android/file.php?var=enc ------enc is string from URLEncoder.encode(myquery, "utf-8");

Comment: Where are you decoding $myq to remove if any slashes put in while encoding? Ofcourse the query wont work if you have slashes in it.So, without decoding, your query looks something like "select x from sometable where x = \'abc\'" and few more characters in between, where it should like "select x from sometable where x = 'abc'". So decode using something like urldecode() (not sure if this is the exact function) before you execute the query.